# in ios 7.1 how can i pass data from Registerion view to Profile view

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, ios7, registration

Hey there I'm trying to pass data from my ***Registration*** controller to view and save the data in new view controller I named ***Profile*** controller.
I don't want to use this method : 
*-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender*
because I am not using the profile controller with a push segue.

The Why I set up every thing is  :

(1) In my "RegistrationController" I created a UItable in a story board then inside the table, the cells I want to be saved and pass on to the other UItable I created named Profile are UIlabel, UItextview, UItextfield .
the way it look is I got a picker at the first cell then other cell after it that shows the picker results (I already got set and working the picker don't put him in the code )
to continue with we got the Description that is for the user to describe in UItextview, what he have been picked from the picker (the picker shows just products names and staff and then the user can describe for other user why he choose this see the pictures...) .
Finally thank you for keep reading this, I've got a cell to insert the user Website address if he have one (this is the UItextfield.

(2) In my "ProfileController" I got the same values that I have in (1) my "RegistrationController" and I just need to know how can I pass and show all the things from **(1)** in view **(2)** .

*The two view are separated in the StoryBoard.
*This data needs to stay in there even after the user closes the app.
*The methods I used for the picker/Registration controller:

```
#import "Picker.h"

#import "LCTableViewPickerControl.h"

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import "OLGhostAlertView.h"

#import "Profile.h"

@interface Picker () <LCItemPickerDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *maskView;

@property (weak) id pickValue;

@end

@implementation Picker

(id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
        return self;
    }

(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma - Alert Methods

(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    OLGhostAlertView *demo = [[OLGhostAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wellcome to MyApp" message:nil timeout:2.0 dismissible:YES];

    demo.position = OLGhostAlertViewPositionTop;
    demo.style = OLGhostAlertViewStyleDark;
    demo.completionBlock = ^(void) {


    OLGhostAlertView *demo2 = [[OLGhostAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please don't forget to fill out all the following Thank You."];

    demo2.position = OLGhostAlertViewPositionCenter;

    demo2.style = OLGhostAlertViewStyleDark;

    demo2.completionBlock = ^(void) {




        OLGhostAlertView *demo3 = [[OLGhostAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wellcome"];

        demo3.style = OLGhostAlertViewStyleDark;

        demo3.completionBlock = ^(void) {




            OLGhostAlertView *demo4 = [[OLGhostAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enjoy from Life Time Account" message:@"You can tap this message to dismiss it." timeout:900.0 dismissible:YES];

            demo4.position = OLGhostAlertViewPositionCenter;

            [demo4 show];
        };
        [demo3 show];
    };
       [demo2 show];
};
   [demo showInView:self.view];
}

(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

(IBAction)show:(id)sender
{

    LCTableViewPickerControl *pickerView = [[LCTableViewPickerControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, kPickerControlWidth, kPickerControlAgeHeight) title:@"Please pick an item" value:_pickValue items:@[@"anthropologie",@"adidas",@"air jordan",@"abercrombie",@"american girl",@"american flyer trains",@"apple",@"android tablet",@"armani",@"Example",@"Example",@"Example",@"Example"                                                                                                                                        
    [pickerView setDelegate:self];
    [pickerView setTag:0];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [pickerView show];
}

(void)dismissPickerControl:(LCTableViewPickerControl*)view
{
    [view dismiss];
}

#pragma mark - LCTableViewPickerDelegate



 (void)selectControl:(LCTableViewPickerControl*)view didSelectWithItem:(id)item
 {

   /*
     Check item is NSString or NSNumber , if it is necessary
   */

   if (view.tag == 0)
   {
      if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
      {
      }
      else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
      {
      }
   }

   self.pickValue = item;

   [_resultLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item]];
   [self dismissPickerControl:view];
}


(void)selectControl:(LCTableViewPickerControl *)view didCancelWithItem:(id)item
{
    [self dismissPickerControl:view];
}

@end
```

Images:
[The Registration Controller.](http://postimg.org/image/by7oot86x/)
[The Profile Controller.](http://postimg.org/image/nsk106vuh/)

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable. And please don't just dump your whole classes here. I have seen the empty default implementations of `initWithStyle:` a million times already. Create a minimal example of the code that does not work as expected and post it.

Comment: I'm Sorry I'm pretty new with coding, I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, the recommended way to pass data between view controllers is to create a segue between the two, and set properties on the destination view controller in the source view controller's implementation of [`prepareForSegue:sender:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue%3asender%3a).

Since you said that isn't an option for you (not sure why), you can do the same thing by instantiating your destination view controller, setting properties on it, and then presenting it with [`presentViewController:animated:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a).

Your code might look something like this:

*RegistrationController.m:*

```
#import "ProfileController.h"

@interface RegistrationController ()
{
    NSString *_userName;
    NSString *_userWebsite;
}

@implementation RegistrationController

- (void)registerUser
{
    ProfileController *profileController = [[ProfileController alloc] init];
    profileController.userName = _userName;
    profileController.userWebsite = _userWebsite;
    [self presentViewController:profileController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

*ProfileController.h:*

```
@interface ProfileController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userWebsite;

@end
```

This example assumes that RegistrationController would assign values to the instance variables `_userName` and `_userWebsite`, and that it would call `registerUser` when it's time to show the ProfileController.

Comment: Thank you very  match mate! I will try to do it soon

Comment: Dosen't work and ProfileController is also a tableview and I want to give the user the option to edit is description aftter he register and then save it . and im not sure about this method you gave me and what about the implementation in ProfileController.m?

Comment: Your question was how to pass data between view controllers, so I'll leave the implementation of your ProfileController to you. The point is, you'll be able to access that data by calling `self.userName` or `self.userWebsite` in ProfileController.

I changed the name of my example method to clear it up. You would have to call that method when you want to transition to the ProfileController. For example, in the action method you assign to that "Next" bar button item in RegisterController, call `[self registerUser]`.

Comment: ProfileController and RegisterController are separated at my storyboard and after the Registercontroller i have anhoter page so its pretty complicated. Maybe i need a database to store all this and then show it after at the ProfileControlelr any way right now i'm stock, what you gave me will not work with my app i need something else like AFNetworking or some thing like that i really don't know i'm new to xcode. *I dont want to pass data its more like store the data at database or somthing and then aftter the user got rgister alerdy and he goes to ProfileController he can see is info there.

Comment: If you need the data to persist between launches, you could try storing the user's info in the [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html), provided it's not a lot of data. You can use `NSUserDefaults` like an `NSDictionary`, setting objects with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:someObject forKey:@"someObjectKey"]` and retrieving them with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"someObjectKey"]`. The `standardUserDefaults` singleton is available anywhere

Comment: Can my code be something as this : [[NSUserDefaults standarUserDefaults] set object:website . or i dont know please can you write it down for me with website for instance so i can understand how this method works thanks!

Comment: You need to assign a key to the object you store in `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, so in your RegistrationController, you could call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_userWebsite forKey:@"userWebsiteKey"];`, and when you want to populate the website field in ProfileController, you could do something like this: `_websiteLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userWebsiteKey"];`.